# Pyinstaller и его работа с кондой

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyinstaller

Народ, хочу спросить по PyInstaller, устанавливал модуль черед конду, конду саму ставил с континуума с питоном 3.6, но проект с pycharm каким-то образом не собирается преобразовываться в exe'шник, грешу на конду с её питоном, выдает вот такое дело, что, собственно, можете посоветовать для решения данного вопроса?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время pyinstaller не поддерживает ([StackOwerflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6), [GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2329))  Python версии 3.6.X и выше.

Как вариант - откат конды на версию Python 3.5.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: В таком случае - примите ответ